# How do I commit the `git diff` of two branches?

Tags: git, controls, gitlab, version, diff

I have made `git diff`ed two branches, and I would like to commit the result of the `diff`; how do I achieve using `git`?

Comment: what do you mean? Save the diff on a file and then add the file and commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to commit the result of the diff;

The question would be: commit *where*? In which branch?

If you diff A and B, and want to commit the diff in B... simply merge A to B

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

Answer (score 1):

Commits save snapshots of files.  Git will *show* a snapshot by comparing it to another, different snapshot, and *show* this diff listing.  But the commit itself is a snapshot, not a diff.

If you want to save a diff listing, put the diff listing in a file, add the file to the set of files that will be saved, and commit.  Usually, saving a diff listing is a bad idea, so be really sure you want to that.